# Ramsey numbers proof

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Why is it that the inequality:

$R(r, b)\leq R(r-1,b)+R(r,b-1)$ holds $\forall r,b \in \mathbb{N}$

Is there some form of conventional proof? Lecturer sent me some notes to have a look at with regards to Ramsey Numbers/Theory, if not a direct proof posted below some links would be helpful if possible.

Cheers

Comment: Do you really mean $R(r-1)$? I think you mean something like $R(r,b)$, right?

Comment: @Arthur yes, this was a typo. I've corrected it now

Comment: The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem) given in the Wikipedia article on the theorem is quite clear.

Comment: So, the proof just assumes that $G$ is a graph on $R(r-1. b) + R(r, b-1)$ edges then considers a vertex $v \in G$ then gathers that $n_{r} + n_{b} + 1 = R(r - 1, b) + R(r, b-1)$ then does some set stuff. Interesting